# Flight path from KML file not showing when exported to ArcMap

Tags: kml, google-earth, arcmap

I am a beginner with Google Earth and would greatly appreciate it if anyone is able to help me out with my inquiry.

I have a KML file which opens fine in Google Earth (found here: [KML File](http://flightaware.com/live/flight/AAL420/history/20130312/0050Z/KDFW/CYYZ/google_earth). It is a file containing a flight path, and I was hoping to export it to ArcMap in order to perform analysis on it.

When I am creating a layer file out of this KML and opening it in ArcMap, I only see the two Placemarks for origin and destination.

Is it possible to have the flight path show as well just like how it is shown in Google Earth?

Thank you in advance for the assistance.

Kindest regards,
Saad

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that ArcMap doesn't support the ["Google eXtension" namespace (gx:)](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#kmlextensions)

I don't see any reference to it in [their online documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/)

If that is the case, to display the track you will need to convert it to a [LineString](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#linestring)

To convert the gx:Track to a LineString, a quick search on google found [RouteConverter](http://routeconverter.com/), which works with a little manual effort.

original output of RouteConverter on a Google Maps API v3 page:
http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/FlightAware_AAL420_KDFW_CYYZ_20130312_ls.kml - 
[on Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http%3a%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2FFlightAware_AAL420_KDFW_CYYZ_20130312_ls.kml&hl=en&sll=38.286842,-88.334385&sspn=20.617514,28.256836&t=m&z=5)

original output on a Google Maps API v3 page with the "Marks" folder removed:
http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/FlightAware_AAL420_KDFW_CYYZ_20130312_lsA.kml - 
[on Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http%3a%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2FFlightAware_AAL420_KDFW_CYYZ_20130312_lsA.kml&hl=en&sll=32.824552,-117.108978&sspn=0.691256,0.883026&t=m&z=5)

Comment: Hello,

Thank you so much for the prompt response.

Could you kindly let me know how I need to go about converting the KML file to a LineString (or direct me to where I can find this information)? 

I am a beginner so I apologize in advance for taking up your time for something that seems to be quite basic.

Comment: I don't do it often enough.  I would probably use a macro in emacs.  A quick search on google found [RouteConverter](http://routeconverter.com/), which looks promising.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time!
I will take a look at this and let you know how it goes.

Kindest regards,
Saad

Comment: Looks like it works with a little less effort.  See my updated answer.